# Date Range Picker component not working inside a modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, modal-dialog, antd

I am trying to use rsuite daterangepicker component and antd's daterangepicker as well but when I try using them inside a React Material UI Dialog/Modal the popup for picking the date won't show or either it shows outside of the modal like this:

[Click Here to check the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBVy5.png)

How can I fix this issue?

Code to check issue:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import MuiDialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import MuiDialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import MuiDialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import { DateRangePicker } from "rsuite";



export default function CustomizedDialogs(props) {

 const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
 const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
 const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    setStart(null);
    setEnd(null);
    setSelected(false);
  };

return(
<div>
  <Dialog
        maxWidth={"xl"}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title"
        open={open}
      >
        <DialogTitle
          id="customized-dialog-title"
          onClose={handleClose}
        >
          Name
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent dividers>
          <div>
                <DateRangePicker
                       appearance="default"
                       placeholder="Select range"
                  />
          </div>
       </DialogContent>
     </Dialog>
</div>

}
```

Comment: You may try increasing the z-index of the date picker so that it's more than the z-index of Modal and make sure daterangepicker binds after the component has been mounted. A bit of code to reproduce the behavior would be better.

Comment: I added a sample code to reproduce also increasing zIndex doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for improving the question. z-index seemed to have worked. Please checkout the answer for a working sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an issue of CSS only.
Checkout the link of a working [sample on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-fog-8kt59?file=/src/App.js)
Only the z-index of the daterangepicker div was changed so that it's more than the z-index of the Modal.

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import MuiDialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import MuiDialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import MuiDialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { DateRangePicker } from "rsuite";
import "rsuite/dist/styles/rsuite-default.css";
import "./styles.css";

const styles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    margin: 0,
    padding: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  closeButton: {
    position: "absolute",
    right: theme.spacing(1),
    top: theme.spacing(1),
    color: theme.palette.grey[500]
  }
});

const DialogTitle = withStyles(styles)((props) => {
  const { children, classes, onClose, ...other } = props;
  return (
    <MuiDialogTitle disableTypography className={classes.root} {...other}>
      <Typography variant="h6">{children}</Typography>
      {onClose ? (
        <IconButton
          aria-label="close"
          className={classes.closeButton}
          onClick={onClose}
        >
          <CloseIcon />
        </IconButton>
      ) : null}
    </MuiDialogTitle>
  );
});

const DialogContent = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}))(MuiDialogContent);

const DialogActions = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    margin: 0,
    padding: theme.spacing(1)
  }
}))(MuiDialogActions);

export default function CustomizedDialogs() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title"
        open={open}
      >
        <DialogTitle id="customized-dialog-title" onClose={handleClose}>
          Modal title
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent dividers>
          <DateRangePicker appearance="default" placeholder="Select range" />
          <Typography gutterBottom>
            Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio,
            dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta
            ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
          </Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom>
            Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.
            Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor
            auctor.
          </Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom>
            Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo
            cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio
            dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.
          </Typography>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button autoFocus onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Save changes
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And the CSS file

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.rs-picker-daterange-menu {
  z-index: 10000000000; /* added a large random number, you can choose it more carefully based on your use-case.*/
}
```